# Azure AD B2C Self-service password reset showing wrong title

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When enabling this new *self service password reset*, it shows wrong titles on the login page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended

It shows these:

```
Sign in with your social account
OR
Sign in with your sign in name
```

But I'm not using any social account, only local account, the *Sign in with your social account* is empty.

I also tried on this sample, removing facebook as social account, having only local account, however it keeps the empty *Sign in with your social account*.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset

Anyone managed to enable *self service password reset* for local account only and having the correct title *Sign in with your sign in name*?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in newest version of content definition. In `TrustFrameworkBase` file use for `api.signuporsignin` the following DataUri:

```
<DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.5</DataUri>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. After upgrading to 2.1.5, the "Sign in with your social account" disappeared

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Using the `Localization` features of the `Identity Experience Framework`. This will allow you to modify the `UxElements` on your Content Definitions. More information can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization.
2. Completely customize the User Interface - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

It took me a minute to test this on one of my policies, but this is what I added to my Sign In/Sign Up page to verify the localization.

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
   <Localization Enabled="true">
     <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
       <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
     </SupportedLanguages>
     <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.en">
       <LocalizedStrings>
         <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="local_intro_generic">Brad</LocalizedString>
       </LocalizedStrings>
     </LocalizedResources>
   </Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

And then updated my Content Definition:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.2</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <LocalizedResourcesReferences>
    <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.selfasserted.en"/>
  </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Comment: The issue here isn't really about changing the title, but whys it is showing _Sign in with your social account_ when there are no social accounts configured.